# JPA ConstraintViolation vs Rollback

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I think I just found that two different JPA implementations work differently for constraint violations and rolling-backs.

```java
@Test(expectedExceptions = @@.class) // CVE or RB?
public void testXXX() {
    final EntityManager manager = LocalPU.createEntityManager();
    try {
        final EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            manager.persist(<wrong>); // this is where CVE coming from
            transaction.commit();     // this is where RB coming from
        } catch (RollbackException re) {
            // <---------------------------------------- hibernate here
            throw re;
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException cve) {
            // <---------------------------------------- eclipselink here
            transaction.rollback();
            throw cve;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

which implementation is working right?

## UPDATE

### NameMustNotBeNull.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL")
public class NameMustNotBeNull {

    protected NameMustNotBeNull() {
        this(null);
    }

    public NameMustNotBeNull(final String name) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
                    generator = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID_GENERATOR")
    @TableGenerator(name = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID_GENERATOR",
                    table = PrimaryKeyValue.TABLE,
                    pkColumnName = PrimaryKeyValue.PK_COLUMN_NAME,
                    valueColumnName = PrimaryKeyValue.VALUE_COLUMN_NAME,
                    pkColumnValue = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID")
    @NotNull
    @XmlTransient
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

### NameMustNotBeNullTest.java

```java
public class NameMustNotBeNullTest {

    @Test(expectedExceptions = RollbackException.class)
    public void testNullName() {

        final EntityManager manager = LocalPU.createEntityManager();
        try {
            final EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            try {
                final NameMustNotBeNull entity = new NameMustNotBeNull(null);
                try {
                    manager.persist(entity);
                } catch (ConstraintViolationException cve) {
                    System.out.println(cve.toString());
                }
                transaction.commit();
                Assert.fail("persisted with null name");
            } catch (RollbackException re) {
                System.out.println(re.toString());
                throw re;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="localPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <!-- I'm testing with one of following providers uncommented -->
    <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>....persistence.NameMustNotBeNull</class>

    <properties>

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby:memory:corrsDB;create=true"/>
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>-->
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>-->

      <!-- eclipselink -->
      <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="target/createDDL.jdbc"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="target/dropDDL.jdbc"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>

      <!-- hibernate -->
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

```
Running ...NameMustNotBeNullTest
1월 17, 2013 11:45:14 오전 org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
```

### org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

```
Running ...NameMustNotBeNullTest
1월 17, 2013 11:50:14 오전 org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

As you can see, Bean Validation seems to be enabled for both providers.

EclipseLink throws CVE on `EntityManager#persist()` with rollback marked.
And Hibernate throws RB on `EntityTransaction#commit()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are more detailed sources about the behavior you have.

According [JPA 2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) (page 102)

> If the set of ConstraintViolation objects returned by the validate method is not
> empty, the persistence provider must throw the javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException containing a reference to the returned set of  ConstraintViolation objects, and
> must mark the transaction for rollback.

And from the [hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e9831)

> If an entity is found to be invalid, the list of constraint violations is propagated by the ConstraintViolationException which exposes the set of ConstraintViolations.
>
> This exception is wrapped in a RollbackException when the violation
> happens at commit time. Otherwise the ConstraintViolationException is
> returned [by Hibernate Validator] (for example when calling flush().)

Additionally, from jpa 2 specs (page 101)

> By default, the default Bean Validation group (the group Default) will be validated upon the pre-persist and pre-update lifecycle validation events

Putting all of this together, I'm little confused because it seems to me that the behavior of HibernatePersistenceProvider doesn't follow the JPA 2 specs since:

- validation must be performed on "pre-presist"
- persistence provider **MUST throw** ConstraintViolationException

And obviously, in your case the `ConstraintViolationException` is not thrown when `persist` is called (and when using HibernatePersistenceProvider).

So according my understanding and to answer your question :

- eclipselink is right
- hibernate is wrong

(note: I hope that someone else can confirm or disagree with my analysis)

---

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

I was confused with my own conclusion. So I tried to reproduce myself the behavior described by the OP and I was unable to reproduce this behavior immediately.

What I did was really similar to what the OP is describing:

- setup a little project, with one entity with a `@NotNull` field.
- trying to persist() an instance with null for `@NotNull` field in a simple test.
- asserting that the `persist()` operation throw a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` + mark the transaction as `rollback only`
- doing this when using eclipselink as persistence provider --> successful
- doing this when using hibernate as persistence provider --> successful

The major difference between my test and the test described the OP was the id generation.
In my successful test, I was using a simple `@GeneratedValue`.

After changing the id generation strategy to :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
        generator = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID_GENERATOR")
@TableGenerator(name = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID_GENERATOR",
        pkColumnValue = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID")
```

I found the exact behavior describe by the OP :

- a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` thrown by `persist()` when using eclipselink.
- no exception at all thrown by `persist()` when using hibernate.

So, when using Hibernate +  `strategy = GenerationType.TABLE` : the behavior is different. I'm quite sure it's not following JPA2 specifications.

Comment: For further readers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978291/hibernate-not-following-jpa-specifications-when-combined-with-bean-validation-ap https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-8028?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: Well... EclipseLink is the RI (Reference Implementation) for JPA. If one has to decide which implementation is right... it has to be EclipseLink, unless if there's a bug. But this would be another matter.

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using? I just came across this when I upgraded from 4.x to 5.x. My entity was using GenerationType.AUTO. I just ran the test using GenerationType.IDENTITY and the test passes using hibernate 5. Looks like a bug in hibernate.

Comment: @MartinCharlesworth It was with hibernate 4.2.0.CR1. (more details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978291/hibernate-not-following-jpa-specifications-when-combined-with-bean-validation-ap and here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8028)

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct.  JPA allows providers to throw EntityExistsException at persist or another PersistenceException at flush/commit, which I have always assumed cover database exceptions.  I don't know Hibernate or the full error you are getting, but I guess that the database exception is occuring and gets wrapped in a RollbackException.

The two tests might not be equivalent though - ConstraintViolationException is not coming from JPA but from validation (JSR-303) that occurs during prepersist.  You must have a bean validation implementation enabled in the EclipseLink test (such as hibernate-validator-4.0.1.GA.jar on the classpath) that might not be enabled in the Hibernate tests.  If you remove bean validation from one or add it to the other, they should behave more similar.

Comment: "JPA allows providers to throw EntityExistsException" can you indicate your source ?

Comment: From the JPA spec, section 3.1.1 javadoc for the EntityManager persist operation.  The question was updated quite a bit since I gave my answer.