# Hibernate not following JPA specifications when combined with Bean Validation API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, bean-validation

This question is a follow up to this one : [JPA ConstraintViolation vs Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354849/jpa-constraintviolation-vs-rollback/14810664)

I did some test about combination of JPA and validation API (JSR-303).

I found the following in [JPA specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) (page 101-102):

> By default, the default Bean Validation group (the group Default) will be validated upon the pre-persist and pre-update lifecycle validation events
>
> ...
>
> If the set of ConstraintViolation objects returned by the validate method is not empty, the persistence provider must throw the javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException containing a reference to the returned set of ConstraintViolation objects, and must mark the transaction for rollback.

I setup the following test:

- HibernateValidator as JSR-303 implementation
- 2 PersistenceProvider Hibernate and EclipseLink
- one entity `NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy` with an id generated with default strategy (`@Generated`) and `@NotNull String name` column
- another entity `NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy` with an id generated with table strategy (`@TableGenerated`) and `@NotNull String name` column
- the test try to `persist` one instance of each entity with a null `name`.
- the expected results are a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` thrown by the persist method and the transaction marked as `rollback only` (i.e. those assumptions are based on JPA specification quoted in this post).

The results are :

- with eclipse link as a provider :

  - the `persist` method throws a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` for both entities.
  - the transaction is marked as `rollback only` in both cases
- with hibernate as a provider :

  - `persist` throws a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` for entity `NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy` + transaction marked as `rollback only`
  - `persist` don't throw any exception for entity `NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy` + transaction **not flagged** as `rollback only`
  - `commit` for `NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy` fails with a `RollbackException`

The questions are :

- is it really a violation of JPA specifications ? or I am missing something with particular case of table generated strategy ?
- in case it is a violation: is there any existing bug report related to it ?

Here is the code for my test:

```
package com.example.jpa.validator;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.RollbackException;

public class ConstraintViolationExceptionTest {

    @Test
    public void testHibernateDefaultStrategy() {  // Success
        testPersistWithNullName("pu-hibernate",new NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHibernateTableStrategy() {
        testPersistWithNullName("pu-hibernate",new NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy());
        //this test fail with :
        //java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException, but persist() succeed !
    }

    @Test
    public void testEclipseLinkDefaultStrategy() {  // Success
        testPersistWithNullName("pu-eclipselink",new NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEclipseLinkTableStrategy() {  // Success
        testPersistWithNullName("pu-eclipselink",new NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy());
    }

    private void testPersistWithNullName(String persistenceUnitName, Object entity){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            final EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            try {
                try {
                    entityManager.persist(entity);
                    Assert.fail("Expecting a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException, but persist() succeed !");
                } catch (javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException cve) {
                    //That's expected
                    Assert.assertTrue("According JPA specs transaction must be flagged as rollback only",transaction.getRollbackOnly());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Assert.assertTrue("According JPA specs transaction must be flagged as rollback only",transaction.getRollbackOnly());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Assert.fail("Expecting a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException, but got " + e.getClass());
                }
                transaction.commit();
                Assert.fail("persisted with null name !!!");
            } catch (RollbackException e) {
                //That's expected
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Assert.fail("Unexpected exception :"+e.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**The entities**

Default strategy

```
package com.example.jpa.validator;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @NotNull public String name;
    public NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy() {}
}
```

Table stategy:

```
package com.example.jpa.validator;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
        generator = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID_GENERATOR")
    @TableGenerator(name = "NAME_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Id @NotNull private Long id;
    @NotNull public String name;
    public NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy() {}
}
```

**The persistence.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="pu-hibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <class>com.example.jpa.validator.NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy</class>
            <class>com.example.jpa.validator.NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem_hibernate"/>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
        <persistence-unit name="pu-eclipselink" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
            <class>com.example.jpa.validator.NameNotNullWithTableGeneratedStrategy</class>
            <class>com.example.jpa.validator.NameNotNullWithDefaultGeneratedStrategy</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

**The pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.example.jpa.validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <hibernate.version>4.2.0.CR1</hibernate.version>
            <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
            <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
            <h2.version>1.3.170</h2.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
                <id>eclipselink</id>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)</name>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
```

Comment: What happens with @Column(nullable=false) along with @NotNull ?

Comment: I tried with `@Column(nullable=false)` : same result

Comment: I really don't understand why generation strategy affects validation in this case, however I would definitely open a bug report as you did already setup a reproducible testcase (well, after stripping away eclipselink part) against hibernate-validator.

Comment: Having just answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172843/spring-data-jpa-bean-validation-in-junit-tests/ along a similar theme, another answer simply uses a `.flush()` call since (their answer states) "JPA invokes Bean Validation only when synchronizing with the database" (**is this true?**). I tested this and it works with non-simple `@GeneratedValue` (so does `.saveAndFlush()`). Just wanted to let you know of a potential "workaround".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I filed a bug report for this : https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-8028